# Which resistor/solution should I use?

Tags: pcb, resistors, soldering

I have (had) an UPS which got wrecked during flight, I disassembled it and found something broken.

I don't really know which resistor should I install or how could I fix it.

[image: Broken PCB]

[image: New crack image]

The other resistors are 1M ohm, the broken pad doesn't make contact with the pins, but there's like multiple pads which make contact with the pins.

Edit 2: New image of the crack. Should I go with the 1005 SMD? It looks more common than the 1004.

Edit 3: I think they're the 1206 since the length is almost 3mm (around 2.6mm) and the wide is something around 1.5mm. Should I should buy a 1206 SMD with 1M ohms and 1004 code, or something like that?

Comment: As mentioned in comments these are likely "bleeder" resistors of some kind, placed in series. From the missing component it looks like the component pads might also be damaged. I'd be very careful when cleaning up the old solder, if you use a wick braid you might risk tearing off a lifted pad. (Also it looks like the joints might have been cold, in which case the whole board needs to be inspected for more assembly problems.)

Comment: Regarding the edit, 1004 means "100 with 4 zeroes after", That is 1,000,000 = 1Mohm. You should naturally use that exact value and not 1005 which would be 10Mohm. It will be super easy to find 1 Mohm 1206 at any of the usual vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit board has been fractured, probably due to something heavy soldered into it or some pressure or impact from outside if shipped without housing.

You should fix that with some epoxy-glass splints and epoxy so the crack does not further propagate. The crack does not appear to go across the wide trace on the left of the board yet.

The resistor as jp314 says is 1M, most likely 1% tolerance. You can determine the size by measuring one of the remaining parts while the part is missing (I would also double check by measuring one to verify it is 1M\$\Omega\$).

Here are the common SMT resistor sizes, table from [here](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-standards-and-codes/resistor-sizes-and-packages/#). Resistor size is related to both power dissipation and voltage capability. A generic replacement will almost surely work, but I would keep to a similar size and the same value of part:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure these are 0805.

Comment: @Lundin Actually, I think 1206 or 0805, but better OP measure it. If 0805 those THT capacitor leads would only be ~0.4mm diameter, which is possible, but a bit flimsy.

Comment: I wonder why they would pick 1206 since the rated power won't matter in this case. Maybe 1206 is friendlier to wave soldering or some argument like that.

Comment: @Lundin The 1206 will have a higher voltage rating

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those are four 100*10^4 = 1 MΩ resistors in series (that's what the '1004' means).

It is probably for measuring a high voltage. You can use a standard 1 MΩ like this:
[image: 1 MΩ]

which might be easier to find. Bend the leads towards each other under the resistor; cut to length and solder.

This is a high voltage circuit, so be careful. Also check that any internal traces on the PCB didn't get damaged.

Comment: The only time I have seen something like that was on compact PCI boards. There was a static discharge bleeder circuit consisting of multiple multi-megohm resistors in series. Their purpose was to bleed off any charge imbalance between a single-board-computer blade and the backplane as the blade was inserted into the backplane. Longwinded way of saying this may not be a voltage divider for an ADC. It may be something else, like a bleed off circuit.

Comment: if I was using a through hole component, I would solder one lead directly to the ground area with a good hot iron, and the other lead directly to the end of R84, taking the already damages solder tracks out of the equation. As it might be high voltage stuff, I might put a bit of sleeving on the non-grounded end.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the 3 other resistors and place a large SMD2512 4 Mohm resistor with HV capability vertically between the pads of R28 and R84. A flexible wire from the R84 pads to the left side across the crack will survive vibrations. Removing the pads and tracks of R31 can improve the creepage distance.